# What land did Isaac sow in and how did he own it?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, parashat-toldot

> וַיִּזְרַע יִצְחָק בָּאָרֶץ הַהִוא ...׃ - Isaac sowed in that land ... [Genesis.26.12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.26.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

I recall Abraham buying a lot in Hebron and Yaakov buying one near Shechem, but I don't recall Isaac buying lands. And I couldn't find commentators elaborating on this.

IIRC our forefathers were very minded about Gezel therefore I suppose they sowed in the lands of their own.

Where was this land he sowed in and how did he own it?

Comment: How are you so sure he owned it?

Comment: @interested I added "*IIRC our forefathers were very minded about Gezel therefore I suppose they sowed in the lands of their own.*"

Comment: @AlBerko Maybe he rented it?

Answer (score 2):

This land is Gerar.

[Rabbeinu Bachya](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.26.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bereshit.26.12.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) writes:

> ויזרע יצחק בארץ ההיא, “Yitzchak planted in that land, etc.” The reason the Torah emphasised “in that land,” is that it was hard ground, did not usually produce much. Considering the fact that the year was one of famine the achievement by Yitzchak in securing a hundredfold return on his seed was all the more remarkable. **The place where he had planted the seed was Gerar**. This is where these remarkable “hidden” miracles happened for him. The land was so parched that when the local people finally found some water, they exclaimed: “we have found water!” (verse 32)

As far as how he came to own it. His father Avraham had it first and was given over to him by Hashem. The [Sifrei (Devarim 8:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.26.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sifrei_Devarim.8.1&lang2=bi) notes:

> ([Devarim 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "which the L-rd swore to your fathers": Why need it be mentioned (in addition to this) "to Abraham, to Isaac, and to Jacob"? (To stress that) each one was worthy of this in himself. An analogy: A king gives his servant one field as a gift, as it is. The servant goes and improves it, not leaving it as it is, but planting a vineyard and bequeaths it to his son — who does not leave it as it is, but improves it and bequeaths it to his son — who does not leave it as it is, but improves it. **Thus, when the Holy One Blessed be He gave the land to our father Abraham, He gave it to him only as it was, viz. ([Bereishis 13:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.13.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "Arise, walk in the land in its length and its breadth, for to you shall I give it." Abraham arose and improved it, viz. ([Ibid. 21:33](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.21.33?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "And he planted a fruit grove in Beersheva." Isaac arose and improved it, viz. (Ibid. 26:12) "And Isaac sowed in that land and he found in that year a hundredfold." Jacob arose and improved it, viz. ([Ibid. 33:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.33.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "And he bought the part of the field where he had pitched his tent."** If so, why need "to your fathers" be written? If in respect to the oath to the fathers, this is already written. This refers to the covenant with the tribes, viz. (Habakkuk 3:9) "the oaths to the tribes, an enduring word."

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand the second part. Hebron and Shechem were given also in that prophecy, however, the two bought the land with money. If Isaac stayed in Gerar did he buy the land, or borrowed or it was nobody's land. I mean legally, not metaphorically.

Comment: I hear! I need to look into it more. Thanks for the +1

Comment: I truly appreciate your effort.